# Program that reads numbers from an array and then insert them into list doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, list

I had to write a program which reads int numbers from an array, and then inserts them one by one if they are bigger than the limit number. What I wrote was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

struct number_list{

    int high_number;
    struct number_list *next;
    };

typedef struct number_list number_list;

void insert_in_list(int *array, int lim);

int main(void){

    int number_seq[SIZE]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int limit;
    scanf("%d\n", limit);
    insert_in_list(number_seq, limit);
    }

void insert_in_list(int *array, int lim){

    int i;
    number_list *start_node;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){

        if(array[i]>lim){

            start_node=malloc(sizeof(number_list));
            start_node->high_number=array[i];
            printf("%d\n", start_node->high_number);
            start_node->next=start_node;
            }

        }

    }
```

What happens is that the program doesn't have any compilation errors (except for a warning that `%d` expects argument of type `*int` instead of `int`, which I also didn't understand, so if anyone could help me with that too would be very kind) but when running, after inserting the limit number, displays a segmentation error (core dump created).

I suppose the problem is in the insert_in_list function, but I don't understand what it is.

Comment: This is mostly C mate, not c++

Comment: The warning for "%d expects argument of type `*int` instead of `int`" would be because `scanf` takes the address of variable as parameter. Hence it should be `scanf("%d\n", &limit);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that go wrong here:

(a) The insert_in_list function needs an additional parameter that tells into **which** list to insert.

(b) Why did you name the member of the number_list structure "high_number". Shouldn't it contain just **a** number and hence simply be called "number"?

(c) You always set the **next** pointer to the structure itself. If you want to form a list, it should point to the next node.

(d) in main you need to define a pointer to the first node of your list, which should contain null as long as the list is empty. This "anchor" is what represents your list.

(e) As a hint: Pass a pointer to that anchor to your insert function, because, once the insert function creates the first node it has to deposit the address of that first node into the anchor. Hence your insert function should look like this:

```
void insert_in_list (number_list** pAnchor, int number)
```

(f) It is no good idea to define the size of your input array as SIZE and use that symbol in your insert_in_list function. Instead, either path the array and its length as two parameter to the function, or -- as I did in the code line above -- pass just one number per call to the insert function and call it for every number you want to insert.

Comment: a) thx, didn't know that. The assignment's text tricked me into thinking only two arguments were needed.

b) there's no real motivation, just because it's higher than the limit.

c) Maybe that's exactly what i don't understand. I don't know how to create a next node once i initialized the first.

d) thx, did that too now.

f) Ok understood. I can't pass just one number though, my assignment wants me to pass the array, the limit and every other parameter necessary to the function.

Comment: You can also add the error for `scanf` that it takes address of integer as parameter for `%d`. Hence it would be `scanf("%d\n",&limit);`

Comment: Is limit supposed to be the number of elements in the array you pass to the function? Then your loop should read:
`for (int i = 0; i <limit; ++i)`

Comment: thx! i'm just stupid and i forgot to add the & operator. Anyway limit is the number before which, other numbers get ignored. Example if i set 4 as limit, only 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 should be inserted in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem however I do not understand why inset_in_list returns nothing and you're not using the list in the main function whatsoever 
If thats not intensional either have it return a pointer to the list or create the list in the main and pass a pointer of the list to the function insert_in_list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct node *node_pointer;
typedef struct node{
    int high_number;
    node_pointer next;
}number_list;
void insert_in_list(int *array, int lim);
int main(void){
    int number_seq[SIZE]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int limit;
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    insert_in_list(number_seq, limit);
}
void insert_in_list(int *array, int lim){
    extern void print_list(node_pointer list);
    int i;
    node_pointer list = NULL;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(array[i]>lim){
            node_pointer newnode, last = list;

            newnode = (node_pointer)malloc(sizeof(number_list));
            newnode->high_number = array[i];
            newnode->next = NULL;
            if (last == NULL){
                list = newnode;
            }//first node
            else{
                while (1) {
                    if (last->next == NULL) {
                        last->next = newnode;
                        break;
                    }
                    last = last->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print_list(list);
}
void print_list(node_pointer list) {
    node_pointer which;
    which = list;
    printf("\nList 4 :");
    if (which == NULL){ printf("Empty\n"); }
    while (which != NULL) {
        printf("%d", which->high_number);
        which = which->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: all good thx. Can you please just explain me the argument of the while statement?

Comment: I'm not sure which while statement you mean but if its the one in insert_in_list, it just navigates to the last node of the linked list and assign its next to the new entry instead of NULL. and the one in print_list just goes through every node :)
I hope I answered you're question